# How to concatenate multiple columns having n no of rows

Tags: excel

I'm trying to concatenate two columns having multiple rows. Which formula or command steps should I follow to get the following:

```
 Col1           col2
John           Smith
Denial         Vos
```

I'm trying to get results like

```
 col1
John smith
Denial vos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [concatenate](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010342288.aspx) function. It would look something like this:

`=CONCATENATE(A:A," ",B:B)`.

Comment: I don't know how much of the sample data suffered typos (e.g. *smith* not *Smith*) but that might have to be `=CONCATENATE(A:A," ",LOWER(B:B))` or even `=PROPER(CONCATENATE(A:A," ",B:B))`. [PROPER function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PROPER-function-f0a33bd9-2dac-4531-a14e-3f28531c8976?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) [LOWER function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOWER-function-588db5d5-2c7f-4752-a9f7-0eb749ba47a5?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)